# Rails Subquery join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, subquery

I have an application that needs to fetch some filters in the database. A filter is a set of `A`, `B` and `C`, i.e. :

```
A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 3
```

Each filter has a value, a characteristic and a category (represented by `A`, `B` and `C`), i.e. :

```
category = 'dimension' and characteristic = 'width'      and value = 10
category = 'color'     and characteristic = 'background' and value = 'red'
```

The data is a little too complicated for the sake of this post but we can assume that the filters always comes in trio :

```
Filter :
  category
  characteristic
  value
```

I need to fetch a certain number of those filters from the database. As filter are applied to a product, the more filter I have, the less products I must find.

My first approach was to do something like :

```
(A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 3) or
(A = 4 and B = 5 and C = 6)
```

But with the previous condition, the result was expanded and not restricted (the filters must add to each other).

A new try gave me :

```
(A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 3) and
(A = 4 and B = 5 and C = 6)
```

But this clearly return nothing because the query try `A = 1 and A = 4`.

Here is a diagram to express what I search :

[image: query diagram]

When I try the query with a `or`, I get all of `(1)` and `(2)`.

```
select * from products where ( category = 'dimension' and characteristic = 'width' and value = 10 ) or ( category = 'color' and characteristic = 'background' and value = 'red' )
```

When I try the query with a `and`, I get none of `(1)` and `(2)`.

```
select * from products where ( category = 'dimension' and characteristic = 'width' and value = 10 ) and ( category = 'color' and characteristic = 'background' and value = 'red' )
```

So a solution was to do some queries and then joins them :

```
select where (A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 3) (1)
select where (A = 4 and B = 5 and C = 6) (2)
select (1) join (2)
```

This way I get all of `(1)` and `(2)` but I keep only the product found in the two subqueries.

But with this solution that I think will work, I am unable to build such query with Active records. The two mains problems are :

- I don't know in advance the number of filters
- I haven't found a proper way to joins subqueries for a case like this one

Do you have any idea/link to recommend ?

Thanks,

Comment: What was wrong with: `(A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 3) or
(A = 4 and B = 5 and C = 6)` ? it seems to do what you need...

Comment: What I want is the intersection of the two conditions : `all that match (1) and (2)`, I'll add a diagram to specify that

Comment: I think you're confusing me because A can't match 1 and 4... and you later statement doesn't explain how that is solved... it just looks like a more complicated way of writing the original "or"

Comment: I add some informations and diagrams then :)

Comment: Sample data and actual SQL would be good too.

Comment: I have no idea how your circles can have an intersection, from the conditions you explaiend

Comment: One product have multiple filter, I didn't specify it because it's complexe. But a product can references multiple trios of filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, using MySQL database, I could simple do a 'OR' condition and then filtering for only the duplicates entries like so :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 
    (category = 'dimension' AND characteristic = 'width' AND value = 10 ) 
 OR (category = 'color' AND characteristic = 'background' AND value = 'red') 
 GROUP BY id 
 HAVING count(*) > 0
```